# How yo mock Overlay, OverlayRef and Injector in angular testing?

Tags: angular

I have a popup service.

```
@Injectable()
export class PopupService {
   private _modal: ModalRef | null = null;
   constructor(private overlay: Overlay,
               private readonly overlayRef: OverlayRef,
               private parentInjector: Injector) {}
   open(data: PopupConfig) {
      const overlayRef = this.overlay.create(this._getModalConfig());
      const modalRef = newModalRef(overlayRef);
      const injector = this._getInjector(data, modelRef, this.parentInjector);
      const portal = new ComponentPortal(PopupComponent, null, injector);
      overlayRef.attach(portal);
      return modalRef;
   }
}
```

My question is that I want to do unit test for this service, but the service has a few dependencies. I don't know how to mock them in the providers. Now the error is `No provider for PopupService`.

I guess that the code might be like

```
providers: [
   Overlay,{provider: Overlay, useValue: fakeOverlay},
   OverlayRef, {provide: OverlayRef, useValue: fakeOverlayRef},
   Injector, {provider: Injector, useValue: fakeInjector}
]
```

The thing is how to create those fake values. I assume

```
const fakeOverlay = jasime.createSpyObj('Overlay', []);
const fakeOverlayRef = jasime.createSpyObj('OverlayRef', []);
const fakeInjector = jasime.createSpyObj('Injector', []);
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. It looks like, you forgot to add `PopupService` to the providers, also use `provide`, not `provider`:

```js
providers: [
  PopupService, // <-- add it
  // provide, not provider
  {provide: Overlay, useValue: fakeOverlay},
  // provide, not provider
  {provide: OverlayRef, useValue: fakeOverlayRef},

  // might now always work, because Angular depends on the real injector.
  // better to mock what the injector gets in your service.
  // provide, not provider
  {provide: Injector, useValue: fakeInjector},
],
```

---

Instead of mocking everything manually, you can use [`ng-mocks`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/) and let it create mocks automatically.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  return MockBuilder(PopupService, ItsModule);
});
```

`ng-mocks` will mock everything what is declared and provided in `ItsModule`, whereas `PopupService` will stay as it is. So all its dependencies will be mocks.

Comment: Do I need to add specific method to `createSpyObj`? Right now it is []. Since I got the error `createSpyObj requires a non-empty array`. But I don't know which method. Also I got the error `No provider for ModalRef!`

Comment: Right, you do need to specify all methods. Or you need to use a library, such as ng-mocks, which knows how to mock services automatically. I've updated my answer with an example of its usage.

Comment: Thanks for your patient. I added the method. For example: const fakeOverlay = jasime.createSpyObj('Overlay', ["create"]); Then it works but it failed if I use a single quote around the method. Now I use double quotes. My IDE is WebStorm.

Comment: Quotes are a part of `lint`, you need to check what you have configured in your project and adjust it to be single / double or ignored.